# Finding the random $r$ in a Paillier encrypted message with knowledge of the private key.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

In the [Paillier cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem), suppose that I know a Ciphertext encrypted with some unknown random $r$ i.e.

$$C = (g^m r^n) \bmod n^2 $$

I know $g, n$, the prime factorization of $n$, i.e., $pq$. I also know the private key $-$ hence I know the message $m$. Would there be a way for me to recover $r$ easily?

Comment: see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/several-questions-about-paillier-cryptosystem